# Detecting a corrupted file when loading data using binaryformatter / deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm working on a videogame where I save/load player savegames using c#'s binaryformatter. This works 99% of the time, but sometimes a user's savegame will get corrupted somehow, and then the game won't be able to read the file. If I could detect when the game encounters this problem, though, I could tell it to load a backup copy of the last good savegame, though, which would be helpful for everyone.

This is how I'm loading the data:

```
       if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + saveLoad.saveFileName))
       {

           BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
           FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + saveLoad.saveFileName, FileMode.Open);
           saveLoad.savedGames = (List<savedGame_latest>)bf.Deserialize(file);
           file.Close();
           success = true;

       }
```

By the way, this is the error when the game loads a corrupted file:

```
EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream
```

Any ideas? What I want is basically a way for the system to detect "oops no, that's corrupted" and to then be shunted to try and load the last safe backup instead.

Comment: put a try round it, if barf, then its corrupted

Comment: The only way of detecting the error is to add a CRC to the file.  You error is occurring because the size of an object in the file is wrong causing you to read more data than in the file.  I would make sure you always call the file.Flush() method before closing a Write file to make sure all data gets written.

Comment: I can't see in the documentation which of your methods could raise an EndOfStreamException. Are you sure the exception is raised in this block?

Answer (score 0):

well you have to open the file to check whether it is opening or not.
what you can do is make a function which check whether the file can be opened or not -

> To check for corrupted file

```
protected virtual bool IsFileCorrupted(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = File.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
       // File is corrupted
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not corrupted
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `BinaryFormatter` stops reading the stream when it finishes you can simply add some hash or checksum value after the saved content without breaking the functionality.

Catching just `EndOfStreamException` detects only one possible corruption anyway.

Saving (`hashAlg` can be any `HashAlgorithm` implementation):

```
new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, savegame); // regular data
var hash = hashAlg.ComputeHash(stream.ToArray());
stream.Write(hash, 0, hash.Length); // hash
```

And loading:

```
int hashLength = hashAlg.HashSize / 8; // get hash size in bytes
var bytes = stream.ToArray();
hash = hashAlg.ComputeHash(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length - hashLength);
if (!hash.SequenceEqual(bytes.Skip(bytes.Length - hashLength)))
    throw new ArgumentException("Savegame Corrupted"); // gotcha!
savegame = (SaveGame)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
return savegame;
```

Try also [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/48CTUZ).